# What is the point of using SAE and then CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to find a suitable pipeline for condition monitoring and one of the suggested pipelines is to use the stacked auto encoder (SAE) and then Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN).

I am not sure what is the benifit of doing this and how using SAE with CNN is different from using SAE only?

Comment: Where did you find this suggestion? Can you edit your post to include a citation and link?

Comment: my professor suggested that. It is not a paper unfortunately. The only thing I was able to come up with is that SAE is more about enhancing the input to more benficial output without reducing the number of paramaters. On the other hand the CNN is more about choosing the best parameters and filtering the input. So, using the SAE outputs as a CNN inputs is about optimzation and then filtering. Does that make sense?

Comment: It's challenging to know what exactly your professor had in mind. Perhaps you could ask your professor for some elaboration on why this is a good idea, and write it up as an answer?

Comment: okay. I will try to have a discussion about that. In case anyone was able to find out why or perhaps has an idea about it, it would be helpful to share! Thank you!

Comment: https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/20/5/1399 one of the literature work.